# context_today() is not defined in XML OpenERP 6

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am using OpenERP-6.0 and Ubuntu-12.04.

Following code is working fine in 7.0 but it's giving error in 6.0

Here is my code:

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_sale_graph">
        <field name="name">Sale Order Graph</field>
        <field name="res_model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">graph,tree</field>
        <field name="domain">[('state', '=', 'In-Process'),('sale_date','&lt;=',time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')),('sale_date','&gt;=', ((context_today() -  relativedelta(months=2)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')))]</field>
        <field name="context">{'group_by':['sale_date']}</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="sale_graph_view"/>
</record>
```

I am facing following error:

```
 File "/home/arbeis/oddo/ydev/oe/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 695, in clean_action
 action['domain'] = eval( action['domain'], eval_ctx ) or []
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'context_today' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

try **datetime.date.today()**

```
(datetime.date.today()  -  relativedelta(months=2))
```

Comment: i try to use datetime.date.today work but i can't group by month on dashboard....in openerp 7.0 my code work group by month but on openerp 6.0 use datetime.date.today data display by date...can help me thanks be fore